# Mobile Browser stripping out 10 digit numbers

Tags: html, django, mobile

I have a Django app that takes user text and relays it to another user.

In some cases the text includes 10 digit phone numbers or 10 digit authorizations.  On mobile devices our users are reporting that any 10 digit number is being removed from the input field.

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load static tags bootstrap4 %}

        
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{% static 'invoiceManager/images/favicon-96x96.png'%}"> -->
    {% appName as name %}
    <title>{{name}} Job Manager</title>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- <meta name="description" content="Use this HTML basic website two percentage column layout template where the navigation menu and the extra stuff are at the same width on the left column, the main content is on the right column.">
    <meta name="generator" content="HAPedit 3.1">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/layout_templates/26.html" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{name}}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Generic ERP system" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.w3docs.com/build/images/logo-amp.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="192" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="192" />
    <meta property="og:image:alt" content="W3dcos" /> -->
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"> 
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'generics/css/button-style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'generics/css/nav-style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'generics/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'generics/css/image-upload.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
    {% comment %}
    imports used to load widget for image upload -- pulled to here for use in formsets
    {% endcomment %}
    <script src="{% static 'generics/js/image-uploader.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'admin/js/image-uploader-modal.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% if '_popup' not in request.META.QUERY_STRING and 'help' not in request.path %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ftco_navbar ftco-navbar-light" id="ftco-navbar">
            <div class="container">
         {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
       Not needed users aren't authen
        {% else %}

        <script id="django-admin-popup-response-constants"
            src="{% static "admin/js/popup_response.js" %}"
            data-popup-response="{{ popup_response_data }}">
        </script>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- END nav -->
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 1rem;">
            <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center">
            {% block container %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
{% block extrascripts %}    
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('form').submit(async function(event) {
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true)
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false)
    });
    
    $('input[type=datetime-local]').on('keydown', function(){return false;})
    $('input[type=time]').on('keydown', function(){return false;})
    $('input[type=date]').on('keydown', function(){return false;})
    $('input[type=datetime-local]').on('click', function(){this.showPicker()})
    $('input[type=time]').on('click', function(){this.showPicker()})
    $('input[type=date]').on('click', function(){this.showPicker()})

</script>
{{ redirect_to_login_immediately }}
{% endblock %}    
</body>
</html>
```

Template Code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block container %}
<div class="text-black">
  {% load bootstrap4 static %}
  {{ form.media }}
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 pb-1">
    <i class="fas fa-cubes fa-2x me-3" style="color: #00bfff;"></i>
    <span class="h1 fw-bold mb-0">{{view.getTitle}}</span>
  </div>

  <!-- <h5 class="fw-normal mb-3 pb-3" style="letter-spacing: 1px;">Sign into your account</h5> -->
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if additional_context %}
    <h3>Additional Job Information/Instructions</h3>
    <div class="pt-1 mb-4">
        <span style="font-weight: 300;">
            {{ additional_context|linebreaks }}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% if 'overview' not in request.path %}
    <div class="pt-1 mb-4">
      <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- <p class="mb-5 pb-lg-2" style="color: #393f81;">Don't have an account? <a href="#!"
        style="color: #393f81;">Register here</a></p>
    <a href="#!" class="small text-muted">Terms of use.</a>
    <a href="#!" class="small text-muted">Privacy policy</a>  -->
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
<script src="{% static 'generics/js/formatting-functions.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

Image from mobile User
[image]

Text to be displayed:
[image]